# Listar arquivos de um diretório contendo nome, tamanho e last modified de arquivos em PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou precisando fazer uma aplicação web que faça a varredura em vários diretórios, pegue o "last modified" e use o tempo para para realizar um cálculo de SLA para alertar na tela do usuário.

Dei uma olhada em alguns códigos em PHP para varrer diretório e consegui fazer esse abaixo.

```
<?php
  if ($dir[strlen($dir)-1] != '/') $dir .= '/';

  if (!is_dir($dir)) return array();

  $dir_objects = array();
  while ($object = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    if (!in_array($object, array('.','..'))) {
      $filename    = $dir.$object;
      $file_object = array(
          'name' => $object,
          'size' => filesize($filename),
          'type' => filetype($filename),
          'time' => date("d/m/Y H:i:s", filemtime($filename))
      );
      $dir_objects[] = $file_object;
    }
  }
  print_r($dir_objects);
?>
```

Obs.: Tenho uma leve experiência com PHP, por isso estou solicitando ajuda. ^^'

Comment: Especifique se o servidor é Windows ou Linux, você também pode dar uma olhada aqui no site do PHP sobre a função stat: https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stat.php

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda João!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer a funcionar!

```
  $path = "/media/Development/robotQuerys";
  $files = scandir($path);
  //var_dump($path);
  //var_dump($files);
  $dirFiles = array();
  foreach($files as $file){
    $filename = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
    if(!is_dir($filename)){
      $info = pathinfo($filename);
      $info["size"] = filesize($filename);
      $info["modified"] = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", filemtime($filename));
      //$info["url"] = "http://".$filename;

      array_push($dirFiles, $info);
    }
  }
  echo "<br/>";
  //var_dump($dirFiles);
  foreach($dirFiles as $file){
    echo "Name: ".$file["basename"]." | Size: ".$file["size"]."KByte | Modified: ".$file["modified"]."<br/>";
```

Obrigado pela ajuda. ;)